# Not Found: /addTodoItem/

Tags: python, django

i work on todo project and have a error.

my models ::

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

my urls ::

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TodoappView , name = "todoappview"),
    path('', views.addTodoItem, name = 'Add Todo Item'),
    path('todoapp/<int:i>/', views.deleteTodoView, name = 'deleteTodoView')
]
```

and my views::

```
def TodoappView(request):
    all_todo_items = models.TodoList.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'todoapp/todolist.html', {'all_items':all_todo_items})


def addTodoItem(request):
    x = request.post['content']
    new_item = models.TodoList(content = x)
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todoapp/')


def deleteTodoView(request, i):
    y = models.TodoList.objects.get(id= i)
    y.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todoapp/')
```

and it is my html file ::

```
<h1>My To Do List</h1>


<form action="/addTodoItem/" method = "post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="content">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Todo Item">
</form>


<ul>
    {% for i in all_items %}
    <li>{{i.content}}
      <form action="/deleteTodoItem/{{i.id}}/" method = "post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" value="Delete">
      </form>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and i have this error :: (Not Found: /addTodoItem/)

Can anyone help me ????!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` module, there is no path which matches `/addTodoItem/`

try to declare the path, like this:

```py
path('addTodoItem/', views.addTodoItem, name = 'AddTodoItem'),
```

EDIT

declare your form like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form action="{% url 'addTodoItem' %}" method = "post">
```

This references your URL by name, rather than by matching on the path.

Comment: i change the path but it doesnt changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path('addtodoitem/', views.addTodoItem, name = 'addtodoitem'),
```

Comment: did you remove the spaces in the name

Comment: yes i did this . my httpresponceredirect is  true???

Comment: add same name in httpresponceredirect('/addtodoitem/')